# Clang: 'cmath' file not found

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, travis-ci, cmath

I'm compiling my project with clang but I'm having an odd error:

```
[ 1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tfs.dir/src/actions.cpp.o
In file included from /home/travis/build/dominique120/miniature-adventure/src/actions.cpp:20:
In file included from /home/travis/build/dominique120/miniature-adventure/src/otpch.h:27:
/home/travis/build/dominique120/miniature-adventure/src/definitions.h:39:10: fatal error:
'cmath' file not found
 #include <cmath>
 ^
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My actions.cpp line 20:

```
#include "otpch.h"
```

otpch.h line 27:

```
#include "definitions.h"
```

definitions.h line 31:

```
#include <cmath>
```

I made a few edits but I have no idea what is causing this error, edits here: https://github.com/dominique120/miniature-adventure/commits/master

PS: GCC just dumps a ton of errors:
https://travis-ci.org/dominique120/miniature-adventure/jobs/21905513

Comment: The errors shown in your "PS" are quite different to the ones in your post

Comment: @MattMcNabb I know, this is why I'm seeking help.

Comment: It sounds like something's wrong with your clang install , hopefully a clang expert can come along and comment. But the gcc errors show that you have some other errors in your code also.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Could you point me in the right direction for finding the problem?

Comment: No, I don't have clang installed

Comment: @MattMcNabb I mean some assistance with the gcc errors.

Comment: I think it'd be best to start a new question for the gcc errors, also post the actual code in the question rather than linking to it.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04 with `libstdc++-11-dev` installed.

After doing:

```
sudo apt install libstdc++-12-dev
```

...the error went away.

It seems to occur with libstdc++-11 only?

Comment: I was getting similar error using c2s from SYCLomatic and it solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I spent 3 days trying to debug this! Am using coc-vim with apt packaged clangd. This worked!

Answer (score 3):

After googling for a problem I was having on macOS, I came to your post. I am sharing a solution, even though it applies only to Mac users.

Chances are you upgraded Xcode (or it was upgraded for you) and you continue to use an old compilation scheme.

Determine which of the following directories actually exists on your disk:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/
```

and make sure that among your compilation switches you have -I along with a directory that exists.

Comment: Given the OP's output showing _"gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"_ this would not seem to have anything at all to do with Xcode, or indeed Macs in general

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't see "Ubuntu/Linaro" in either the OP's original or the subsequent edit. Might you have been intended the comment to go elsewhere? In any case, I added a disclaimer, but I am not deleting the answer as this is a tricky problem with a fairly straight-forward solution.

Comment: Click on the links in the question. I concede that this information _should_ have been in the question itself, but the fact remains that the OP is not on Mac and is not using Xcode. Anyway with your disclaimer it's fine now, and potentially useful for future visitors, so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with clang 14 on ubuntu 23.04. In my case it was fixed by removing `libgcc-13-dev`. Before removing:

```
clang++-14 -v          
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.6
<snip>
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13
```

After:

```
clang++-14 -v
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.6
<snip>
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to have matching libgcc and libstdc++?